# Maintaining the total of a large number of floats

Tags: floating-point

My program maintains an array of around 50,000 floats. The total of these numbers is an important quantity, which must be kept up to date as array elements change. There is an obvious way to do this, where `numbers` is the array, and `total` is their total:

```
function update_number(int index, float new_value) {
    total += new_value - numbers[index];
    numbers[index] = new_value;
}
```

I am concerned about floating point rounding errors leading to drift of the value `total` compared to the true total. How much of an issue is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most well-known algorithm for summing a large number of floats as precisely as possible is known as [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). While the algorithm as it stands is not written to allow addends to change, it's trivial to adapt it. Just keep the running error value around after you've computed the initial sum, and update the sum by adding the negation of the previous value and then adding the new value.

Unfortunately, Kahan summation doesn't provide great worst-case guarantees if a lot of your numbers are negative... and the update step guarantees that there will be. (In fact, the condition number will tend to zero after enough updates, meaning that the error will be unbounded!) So while you *can* use Kahan summation, and your error will *probably* be small, I personally wouldn't chance it.

Another, better option is [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation), which provides extremely good precision in practice. In pairwise summation, you recursively find the pairwise sum of the first and second halves of the array, then sum the results. Think of it as a binary tree, with the leaves holding your numbers, each internal node holding the sum of its two child nodes, and the root holding the sum of all leaves.

To make pairwise summation into an updatable algorithm, simply keep all the tree nodes around. For each updated value, change the target leaf, then recompute all its ancestors back to the root. That only requires `log2(n)` sums per update, and `n` extra values to keep around.